# Css menu item selection issue jQuery/cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

Hi all I am developing a application in cakephp and have defined a element menu_top.ctp as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var path =location.pathname;
```

`

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(path);
        /* select the menu nav tab based on the url */
        $("#menu li a[href='" + [ path ] + "']").parents("li").each(function() { 
            $(this).addClass("current-menu-item");
        });

    });
</script>
<div id="welcomeMsg">
<?php 

    if($session->check('Auth.User')):
     echo "<span style='float:right;color:#ffffff;'> Welcome ".$session->read('Auth.User.username')."</span>";
    endif       
?>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="topNav"> 
    <?php 
        if($session->check('Auth.User')): ?>
            <ul id="menu" style="margin-top:10px;">
                <li>
                  <?php echo $this->Html->link('Home',array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home')); ?>
                </li>
                    <?php if($session->read('Auth.User.admin') == 1): ?>
                 <li class="">
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Admin',array('controller' => 'admin','action'=>'index')); ?>
                </li>
                <?php endif ?>
                <li class="">
                  <?php echo $this->Html->link('Terms & Conditions/Privacy Policy',array('controller' => 'toc','action'=>'index')); ?>
                 </li>

                <li class="">
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Contact Us',array('controller' => 'contact','action'=>'index')); ?>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                     <?php echo $this->Html->link('About Us',array('controller' => 'about','action'=>'index')); ?>
                </li>
                  <li class="">
                     <?php echo $this->Html->link('Log Out',array('controller' => 'users','action'=>'logout')); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

The jquery code defined above selects menu item when top level url are opened in browser for eg. `http://localhost/mysite/admin` will select admin tab but when I open `http://localhost/mysite/admin/users` the selection is lost.
Please help me to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In `document.ready` function, change the selector from

```
"#menu li a[href='" + [ path ] + "']"
```

to

```
"#menu li a[href^='" + [ path ] + "']"
```

(notice the ^ sign before =)

Source:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings